# LibGDX Texture not Showing Correctly

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So i have a problem which is i am Developing a Pacman Clone and i have a Game State that i Render using LibGDX . The Game State Works Very good on the first Level . But when i Dispose it and add a New Game State some of the Textures become a black box like in the picture . Not all of them though . These Textures are Statics that doesn't Get Reloaded . i tried using Sprites instead . still same problem [image]